# Indexing into JSON object

Tags: json, swift

I have a JSON object in the shape of:

```
let allSnippets = [<METDocument key: <collection: snippets, ID: xNmjQH5N3HbomnATk>, fields: {
        text = "First snippet";
    }>, <METDocument key: <collection: snippets, ID: KvQWnWfyto5iXXsni>, fields: {
        text = "Second snippet";
    }>]
```

How can I index into this and for example get the text "Second snippet" from the fields ?

I tried this:

```
    let json = JSON(allSnippets)
    if let text = json[1]["text"].string{
        print(text)
    }
```

but that did not work.

Comment: Of what type is `allSnippets`? Where is `METDocument` from?

Comment: @kametrixom The object might be an NSArray, or a JSON I am not sure.  

See part where is explain: All documents in a collection can be accessed as an NSArray:

https://github.com/martijnwalraven/meteor-ios/wiki/Usage-without-Core-Data

Comment: In that case, you can't. `SwiftyJSON` is made for parsing JSON files and nothing else. You can't just trivially convert some data to JSON.

Comment: @kametrixom ok, do you have a suggestion on how I can index into the fields part?  I found that allSnippets[1] will give me the second "document", but how do I only get the string "Second Snippet" ?